# What is pip install -q -e . for in this Travis-CI build tutorial?

Tags: python, django, pip, travis-ci

I'm following [this tutorial](http://cramer.io/2012/05/03/using-travis-ci/) for testing a Django project with Travis-CI. In this example script:

```
env:
  - DJANGO=1.2.7
  - DJANGO=1.3.1
  - DJANGO=1.4
install:
  - pip install -q Django==$DJANGO --use-mirrors
  - pip install -q -e . --use-mirrors
```

What exactly does `pip install -q -e .` perform? There is no -q flag and I'm not sure what the meaning of this is for `-e` is in the [pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-e):

> [-e flag]: Install a project in editable mode (i.e. setuptools "develop mode") from a local project path or a VCS url.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`-q` means quiet (to control the console log level).

`-e` is for you install a local directory as a package. Suppose you check out `flask` to `~/flask`, then `pip install -e ~/flask` will symlink your `~/flask` to your `site-packages` directory.

Comment: does the `.` in the command mean that the current working directory gets symlinked to the `site-packages` directory?

Comment: @YPCrumble Yes, the `.` means the working directory, although it's technically not a symlink. pip adds an `.egg-link` file to the `site-packages` directory, which for all intents and purposes acts like a symlink to Python's module resolution.

Comment: Also there's `easy-install.pth` in `site-packages`/`dist-packages` that gets added the path to your "dev project" directory.